# Remove text from string with JScript

Tags: replace, jscript

I have a JScript which iterates through selected elements in the project browser. What I would like to do is to remove a part of the name string.

Example name:

> "Random name (other text)"

I would like the script to change the name to "Random name". For this example I always want to remove the brackets and the text inside the brackets.

How do I do this with JScript? Replace?

Answer (score 0):

The function **split** solved my issue:

```
        oldName = e.Name;
        newName = oldName.split(" (");
        e.Name = newName[0];
```